# Tensorflow, Keras: How to create a trainable variable that only update in specific positions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient-descent, tensor

For example, `y=Ax`

where `A` is an diagonal matrix, with its trainable weights (`w1, w2, w3`) on the diagonal.

```
A = [w1 ... ...
    ...  w2 ...
    ... ... w3]
```

How to create such trainable `A` in Tensorflow or Keras?

If I try `A = tf.Variable(np.eye(3))`, the total number of trainable weights would be 3*3=9, not 3. Because I **only** want to update (w1,w2,w3) that 3 weights.

A trick may be to use `A = tf.Variable([1, 1, 1]) * np.eye(3)`, so that the 3 trainable weights are mapped into the diagonal of `A`.

My question is:

1. Would that trick work for my purpose? Would the gradient be correctly calculated?
2. What if the situation of `A` is more complicated? E.g. if I want to create:

[image: More complex Example]

where the `w1, w2, ..., w6` are weights to be updated.

Comment: You can use layer.trainable = False or True to create a trainable layer in Keras. But I think you will find a problem in Gradient calculation because it needs matrix operation and you can find some element changeable and other constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different tools to address this problem.

1. You can create the variables you need and rearrange them into the desired form.
2. You can create more variables than you need then discard some to reach the desired form.

Both approach are not exclusive and you could you a mix of successives steps of type #1 and #2.

For example, for your first example (diagonal matrix), we can use approach #1.

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n))
A = tf.diag(w) # creates a diagonal matrix with elements of w
```

For your second, more complex example, we could use approach #2.

```
A = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((n, n)))
A = tf.matrix_band_part(A, 1, 1) # keep only the central band of width 3
A = tf.matrix_set_diag(A, tf.ones(n)) # set diagonal to 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more complex case where `A` needs to be divided in sections where only some parts are trainable and others can have arbitrary values, the easiest thing to do would be to build the individual sections and then concatenate them together.

For example I needed weight matrix `A` of arbitrary size that (for size 4x4) looks like this (4 distinct sections of 2x2):

```
#  [[0.,   0.,   -0.2,    0.],
#   [0.,   0.,   0.,      -0.2],
#   [0.35, 0.,   train,   train],
#   [0.,   0.35, train,   train]]
```

Code to make this:

```
n_neurons = 3
zero_quarter = tf.zeros((n_neurons, n_neurons))  # upper left quarter are zeros
neg_diag = tf.diag(tf.ones(n_neurons) * -0.2)  # upper right is negative diag
pos_diag = tf.diag(tf.ones(n_neurons) * 0.35)  # lower left is positive diag
# lower right quarter is trainable randomly initialized vars
train_quarter = tf.get_variable(name='TrainableWeights', shape=[n_neurons, n_neurons])

weights_row0 = tf.concat([zero_quarter, neg_diag], axis=1)
weights_row1 = tf.concat([pos_diag, train_quarter], axis=1)

weights = tf.concat([weights_row0, weights_row1], axis=0)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(weights))
```

And the result is:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.         -0.2         0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.2         0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.2       ]
 [ 0.35        0.          0.         -0.61401606  0.39812732  0.72078323]
 [ 0.          0.35        0.         -0.34560132  0.40494204  0.36660933]
 [ 0.          0.          0.35        0.34820676  0.5112138  -0.97605824]]
```

where only the bottom right 3x3 section is trainable.

Answer (score 0):

Both creating a variable of vector or matrix works fine

for question 1.

Don't worry, gradients will be calculated correctly

for question 2.

If it becomes more complex, like your mentioned, you can still create a variable of vector and then build matrix from  that variable.

Alternatively, you can create a variable of matrix, and then update only part of them with `tf.scatter_update` instead of `tf.assign`